# Spring State Machine: Wrong state in StateMachineListener.stateMachineStopped()

Tags: java, spring, ssm

Inside the stateMachineStopped method, when asking the state machine for its current state, I sometimes get the wrong state. It gives me the state before the last transition. However, the right state is returned in the code following the last state transition.

I have the *impression* it's only happening when restoring the SSM context from serialized form. I am using Kryo and StateMachinePersister to save- and restore workflows.

Does this ring a bell for somebody ?

Using SSM 1.2.6 btw.